# Python program finishes before GDown has finished downloading

Tags: python, python-3.x, download, google-drive-api

I have an array of google drive links:

```
links = ["https://drive.google.com/open?id=...", "https://drive.google.com/open?id=..."]
```

To download each file in the array I loop through each one to download:

```
for link in links:
    try:
       gdown.download(link, fullfilename, quiet=False)
    except (ValueError, IOError, RuntimeError) as e:
       print(" the downloader encountered an error with the link: " +e)
```

However, the program runs through the array loop nearly instantly and finishes the program before `gdown` gets a chance to download anything. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Download a file stored on Google Drive**

From the way your code is trying to run the array, you are missing the parameters to log data if the file has been downloaded or the percentage of the file. This could be the reason why your code just reads the download request but does not verify any progress itself.

As suggested by the official documentation. The best way to download the Drive files should be like the snippet:

```js
   def download_file(real_file_id):
    """Downloads a file
    Args:
        real_file_id: ID of the file to download
    Returns : IO object with location.

    Load pre-authorized user credentials from the environment.
    TODO(developer) - See https://developers.google.com/identity
    for guides on implementing OAuth2 for the application.
    """
    creds, _ = google.auth.default()

    try:
        # create drive api client
        service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

        file_id = real_file_id

        # pylint: disable=maybe-no-member
        request = service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
        file = io.BytesIO()
        downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(file, request)
        done = False
        while done is False:
            status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
            print(F'Download {int(status.progress() * 100)}.')

    except HttpError as error:
        print(F'An error occurred: {error}')
        file = None

    return file.getvalue()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    download_file(real_file_id='1KuPmvGq8yoYgbfW74OENMCB5H0n_2Jm9')
```

**References**

- https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-downloads#python